# I want to calculate filesize before export csv/xls (Laravel, Maatwebsite)

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In my below code Excel::create function is creating a new csc/xls file and ->download function is downloading the file,
I want some function that could calculate file size.

I have searched a lot but couldn't get any solution.

```
$data = Item::get()->toArray();

return Excel::create('itsolutionstuff_example', function($excel) use ($data) {
    $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
    {
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
})->download('csv');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store file locally and serve the file from a path.

In your blade, you can check the filesize of your stored file:

```
{{ File::size(public_path('path_of_file')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate Laravel excel does not provide any API to get the file size before even it is created.

There is a work around you can create a file on the run time you can get the size of the file using file_metadata

```
 $data = Item::get()->toArray();

 Excel::create('itsolutionstuff_example', function($excel) use ($data) {
    $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data){
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
 })->store('filename');

 File::size('filename'); // get file size
```

Hope this helps.